# Counter-intuitive behavior of SUM( ) of UNION in Sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I ran this code in an sqlite3 terminal (version 3.29.0), and the result is a little strange:

```
sqlite> select sum((select 4 union all select 2 ));
4
sqlite> select sum((select 4 union select 2 ));
2
```

I understand why union reverses the table, but why does `sum` choose the first element?

Meanwhile, this code works just as expected:

```
sqlite> select sum(x) from (select 4 as x union all select 2 as x);
6
```

Is this the intended behavior, or is this a bug in sqlite? And if it's intended, what's the logic (and semantics) behind it?

Comment: Should raise an error, the sub-query isn't allowed to return more than 1 row.

Comment: @jarlh Not in SQLite. It works and returns the results mentioned in the question.

Comment: Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8dywVWwApXMw3BCitixwzT/0

Comment: I rest my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected behavior.

From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) (emphasis added)

> A SELECT statement enclosed in parentheses is a subquery. All types of SELECT statement, including aggregate and compound SELECT queries (queries with keywords like UNION or EXCEPT) are allowed as scalar subqueries. **The value of a subquery expression is the first row of the result from the enclosed SELECT statement.** The value of a subquery expression is NULL if the enclosed SELECT statement returns no rows.

The `UNION` example just happened to end up returning.rows in a different order than the `UNION ALL` one. Without an `ORDER BY` neither one is guaranteed to use a particular order, though.

Comment: I understand now, the subquery is reduced to a single value before even reaching sum(). And it behaves differently from a "SELECT statement enclosed in parentheses" when it follows `FROM`.